# Swift - NSUserDefaults Having value or not?

Tags: ios, swift

My App crashing due to Empty or null value from NSUserDefaults. How to validate NSUSerdefaults Having value or not?

```
let empName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("EMP_NAME")

        lblUserName.text = "Hello I'm \(empName!)"
```

Comment: By not using the crash operator `!`, and instead [dealing with the optional values properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)?

Comment: If you want help with your issue you should update your question with relevant code.

Comment: Now i added my code.

Comment: @originaluser2 I love the phrase "crash operator". This needs to be an official coined phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below possible conditions.

**1. Check NSUserDefaults is null:**

```
if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("EMP_NAME") == nil)
{
   print("NULL")
}
```

**2. Check NSUserDefaults String is null or Empty:**

```
if((NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("EMP_NAME")) == "" || NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("EMP_NAME") == nil)
{
   print("NULL or Empty String")
}
```

Comment: Why did you delete your first answer and repost it again exactly as it was? That's not the way to get around a down vote.

Comment: I am trying to edit. But its duplicated so only i removed one answer. @rmaddy

Comment: @PREMKUMAR You can freely [edit your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37487828/edit) without having to re-post.

Comment: @originaluser2 oh fine. Now i need to remove this post and unDelete old post and i can edit?

Comment: @PREMKUMAR Just leave it be, no point in unnecessarily deleting and un-deleting. Just make sure to bear it in mind for the future – it certainly looks incredibly suspicious if you delete a post with a down-vote on it and then re-post it. Also bear in mind that people with 10k+ rep can see deleted posts.

Comment: @originaluser2 Yes i understood.